# python puts data in firebase realtime database, but angular grabs data from cloud firestore

Tags: python, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a python program that writes data to a firebase database using firebase-admin.  This stores the information in a realtime database.  But when I build an angular app, it looks in the cloud firestore.

In my angular app, this code I use in my service to get the data:

```
constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {}
getData(){
this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
}
```

The code in my Python app that puts the data in the realtime db:

```
from firebase_admin import db
ref = db.reference('items')
ref.set({myobject here})
```

I've searched all day on either having python write to the cloud firestore, or angular read a realtime database.  Picture here shows the two databases I'm dealing with.  My data goes in one place, but my angular app pulls from the other.

[image: Image here shows the two databases]

Comment: So what exactly is your question/problem? Or in other words: What do you want to happen?

Comment: Basically my issue is I will have a raspberry pi running a script to monitor temperature in a building at one place, and I wanted to see the data at a remote location.  I built the python app and ran it on the pi.  It is successfully adding the data to the firebase realtime database.  However, when I built my angular web page I was going to monitor it with, the data was empty.  After some troubleshooting I discovered the angular app was looking at the cloud firestore for the data, not the realtime db.

Comment: And what is stopping you from having your angular app look at the realtime db instead of firestore? There should be planty of examples and resources for that online. Like [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Comment: That link you shared is exactly what I tried.  It doesn't grab data from the realtime database.  No example I've tried online does.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfqeh5 is an example of what I built.  It doesn't get the data in the realtime db.